# Using multiple colours in the same symbol in arcmap 10.4

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I am working on a map of the Rainy-Lake of the Woods watershed on the U.S.-Canada border.

I have created a shapefile of water quality monitoring stations in the basin using data from USGS and Environment and Climate Change Canada (ECCC). I have attached a screenshot of the Excel spreadsheet I'm basing it off of below.

[image: screenshot of my water quality monitoring stations spreadsheet]

Is there a way to split a symbol by multiple colours in arcmap to not only show whether the station is run by USGS or ECCC, but also whether they measure water quality, water flow, and water levels (using yes or no variables)? I have tried using the Multiple Attributes function but I'm limited to only three values.

[image]

In other words, is it even possible to do or am I stuck with Multiple Attributes?

Comment: yes it is possible but you will need to add and calculate a new field.  create a new field called 'code' (or whatever) and calculate so eccc,no,no,no = 1; eccc,no,no,yes = 2; and so on.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to add an extra field that has a unique value for every possible combination of field values you have. Then you can use that field for symbolization.

Another way would be to duplicate the layer a few times (possibly inside a group layer), and have a separate layer for every attribute you want to symbolize. It should be possible to specify an offset for the symbol, so one is move slightly to the topleft, one to the topright etc.

Finally, you could have two layers, one for USGS and one for ECCC, and use a 'multiple attributes' renderer for the three remaining attributes.